# Is there a way for one .NET Control to contain another Control which is owned by a seperate GUI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, user-interface

I'm looking at creating a tabbed interface which has user controls (possibly written by plug-in developers) within a tabbed or MDI interface.  These plug-in controls could unintentionally freeze their GUI thread, and I'd prefer that they not influence user controls in other tabs.  Much like Google Chrome creates a process for each tab; but in this case, just threads.

Or perhaps even an MDI interface where the child MDI forms are owned by separate threads?

I've found that while I can run multiple GUI threads at once, the Form level is where they MUST be separated.  Any workarounds/ideas?

**For those saying this shouldn't be needed, I call bullshit.  Google's Chrome browser runs tabs in separate processes for security and UI reasons.  I'm merely trying to duplicate this behavior.  When the people writing the user controls are sucky plug-in developers, this is important.**

Comment: Don't make user controls which freeze their GUI thread. WTF!

Comment: `freeze their gui thread`? Why would you want to do this? By design or due to limitation?

Comment: I think people are misinterpreting your intentions. I don't think you're asking how to freeze user controls on other tabs, I think you're asking how to prevent user controls from freezing the application while your application is busy processing a long-running request. If that's true, you might want to reword your question.

Comment: @senfo: That's what I thought so!

Comment: Thankfully no, you cannot do this, and there is no reason to anyway.

Comment: When you work for a large organization, developers design controls which can be faulty.  I'm not forgiving it, but accepting it.  I'd like to be able to isolate them.  It's not a perfect development world...

Comment: @Ed Then why did Google design Chrome with separate processes running tabs?  Was there no reason?

Comment: @senfo No, that's not what I'm asking.  I'm asking exactly what I said above.  I added the information about plugin developers to make the situation sound more feasible.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi, your Chrome comparison doesn't make sense. Isolation is the reason that Chrome and Internet Explorer 8 were designed to run tabs in separate processes. The controls are still part of the main UI thread, the page processing is done in a separate process. If you can't isolate the processing that the controls are performing, you have a major design flaw. Don't accept it. Fix it.

Comment: @senfo how do I fix other users' plugins?!

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi, I don't have the details on the project, but is this something controlled internally? Talk with the people that designed these controls and point out the flaws in their design. This doesn't need to be a negative conversation, but it needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible to do this in the way you are describing.  A control which is owned / affinitized to another GUI thread cannot be directly contained within a control which is owned / affinitized to a different thread in such a way that it's paint function runs on the other thread.

Comment: Do not like.  They should marshal the call if they need to damnit!  :).  How about in WPF?

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi, same for WPF :(.  At least for all of the mutable types.  It may be possible with the few immutable / frezzable types.  Don't know enough to say definitively though.

Comment: Why do you "not like"?  What use case do you have that can only be solved with your appraoch and cannot be solved by invoking a method on another thread?

Comment: @Ed This application allows users to install plugins written outside of my control.  If these plugins cause GUI delays - my application is blamed.  It's very similar to the Chrome issue.  I'd rather see "Aw Snap" like Google shows when a tab goes bad then have the whole application go bad.  When a given plugin dies/locks up, it's clearer who the blame lies with if the entire application doesn't die.  

Don't be so fast to jump to conculsions.  I'm not an idiot.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi: If plug-ins don't have to conform to any particular pre-existing API, one approach would be to not give the plug-ins any access to the UI thread, but instead have them draw to off-screen buffers.  Performance would not be wonderful, but you could better prevent them from wreaking havoc on the system.  If you can accept the performance hit, you could even relegate the plug-ins to their own appdomain or process.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to fix this situation is to write UserControls that don't perform long-running tasks on the UI thread.  If the control is blocking and waiting on some computational task, fix *that*.  Make that task run in the background, and have the control display some non-compute-intensive content until it's done.  If that task freezes, the control will be frozen in its "I'm waiting..." state, but it won't intrude on the rest of the UI.

If you're using a third-party control that you can't fix, well, in the immortal words of Jay-Z, I feel bad for you, son.

Comment: No, it's seriously not, and in this case I'm afraid there's probably nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, controls shouldn't be performing any processing. Their purpose is to provide interactivity between the user and the application. For example, it is not the job of a button to fetch data from a database and present it to the user. That being said, hopefully you are doing your processing in a controls event handler, such as the Click event on the Button control. In your event handler, you can prevent the UI from appearing "hung" by processing tasks in a background thread. The [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is often useful in these situations.

I suggest reading up on Threading. [The Microsoft® .NET Framework Application Development Foundation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626197) book has a section on threading (even if no other certification books are read, I at least recommend all .NET developers read this book). Just remember not to update the UI from a child thread. Read an example on [how to make a thread-safe call to Windows controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28VS.80%29.aspx) if you're not familiar with this approach.

Comment: I do not need to read up on threads.  I've written a ton of multi-threaded software. I know that the original question IS possible - but perhaps not in .NET.  I am allowing users to dynamically load plugins, and drop them onto a new tab.  Thus, said plugin should be isolated.  I am not asking for tips on threading and control development - just advice on how to solve the problem stated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having or owning different GUI threads, you should view the whole issue from a different angle. Why would you want a thread associated to tab's child control to be freezed? If it does freeze and everything else feezes too, threading aside, that's not done right from ground up.

What `JaredPar` pointed out is correct, but that doesn't mean you cannot achieve what you want. I assume you want stuff running within a tab to continue running/stopping without affecting other controls and user-experience.

I've done it before in a complex WinForm app. Here are some readings which might give you more insights:
[Threading out tasks in a C#.NET GUI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/csharp_guithreads.aspx)
[Thread and GUI](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Thread/ThreadandGUI.htm)
[Updating GUI from Other Threads in C#](http://jamesrossiter.wordpress.com/2008/08/22/updating-gui-from-other-threads-in-c/)
[Advanced Techniques To Avoid And Detect Deadlocks In .NET Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163618.aspx)